# Flutter : How to get spoken words as text from video

Tags: flutter, video, flutter-dependencies, speech-recognition

Im working on a video player app.I have used video_player: ^2.6.0 package. I when i upload a video i want to get all the words spoken from the video so that i can show as subtitle and highlight the spoken words. I have tried with the below code but it skips some words as the controller time moves faster then some small words spoken

Below is the code to get current word

```
getCurrentSpokenWord(_controller.value.position.inMilliseconds)

String getCurrentSpokenWord(int currentPosition) {
    String currentWord = "";
    

    for (int i = 0; i < response.transcribeSentences!.length; i++) {
      for (int j = 0; j < response.transcribeSentences![i].words!.length; j++) {
        final word = response.transcribeSentences![i].words![j];
        final wordStartTime = word.startTime! * 1000;
        final wordEndTime = word.endTime! * 1000;

        if (currentPosition >= wordStartTime && currentPosition < wordEndTime) {
          currentWord = word.word!;
          //break;
          return currentWord;
        }
        
      }
    }
  
    return currentWord;
  }
```

is there any other way or any library to do the same?